# Redirection after login to another page is not working for server + Chrome issue

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect-url

I have set previous URL like below in controller

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
```

After login, it will be redirect to previous url. It's working for Firefox but not working for chrome.

> System -> Customer configuration ->Redirect Customer to Account
>   Dashboard after Logging in -> set to NO

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in controller to redirect to previous URL:

```
$this->_redirectReferer()
```

Comment: No..It's not working... For firefox it works fine..but for chrome, it redirects to account dashboard..

Comment: Try this on Private window for both browser. I think some other issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is cookie setting issue in your system. Try in incognito mode on chrome. Also check cookie setting at magento admin.

Comment: No..It's not working... i tried

Comment: Clear `var/cache` folder and `var/session`